# Zend Framework hostname routing

Tags: zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname("test", array('controller'=>'mycontroller'));
```

This works fine, and redirects requests to the index action in 'mycontroller'.

What I need to do is to be able to call the following url:

```
http://test/myaction
```

Where the action called is mycontroller->myaction

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname)

> Hostname routes can, but never should be used as is. The reason behind that is, that a hostname route alone would match any path. So what you have to do is to chain a path route to the hostname route. This is done like in the example by calling `$hostnameRoute->chain($pathRoute);`. By doing this, `$hostnameRoute` isn't modified, but a new route (`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain`) is returned, which can then be given to the router.

Given there are no actual variable components in your hostname route, it's quite redundant. You're better off just sticking with a [Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) or [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static) if there are no variable parts to your routes.

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand what you mean. There will be multiple host routes. Some, like the example, will have variable actions.

What I kind of want to achieve is to have the host determine the controller, and if no path specified, use the index action. If any action is specified. So: 

`code`http://test/

Would use the mycontroller and the index action, while:

`code`http://test/myaction/

would use the mycontroller and the myaction action.